# Why is the life of Ubuntu 13.04 so short?

Tags: release-management

Looking at the [release page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), I noticed the short life of 13.04. It is only 8 months : April 2013 to January 2014.

Why is the life of 13.04 so short?

Comment: To add to the answers already given: If you want stability, always use the LTS (Long Term Support) releases (the last was 12.04 and the next will be 14.04). If you want the "latest and greatest", use the in-between releases, but be prepared to upgrade every six months or so and suffer frequent teething problems.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Canonical switched to a 9 month support plan for non LTS releases because back-porting bugs and package upgrades was consuming too much time for the company, since most users of non-LTS releases upgrade each cycle.

Source: Too much time wasted reading about Linux.

Comment: +1 for source. (experimental question:) as an experimented time-waster, could you rec[ommend] sources that are *balancing between* being utterly useful and/or up-to-date, and wasting *too much* time, to aid (or salvage) fellow time-wasters?

Comment: OMG! Ubuntu is pretty neat for a bird's eye view. They are pretty on the ball about small changes in Ubuntu. Try also, "Linux Action Show", reddit.com/r/linux, Web Upd8, Phoronix, linux.com/news.

Answer (score 27):

After further browsing, I found [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes?action=show&redirect=RaringRingtail/TechnicalOverview#Support_lifespan_reduced) :

> Ubuntu 13.04 will only be supported for 9 months. Previous non-LTS releases were supported for 18 months. For more information, please read the announcements [here](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/03/19/changes-in-ubuntu-releases-decided-by-the-ubuntu-technical-board/) or [here](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/03/19/ubuntu-technical-board-looks-at-shuttleworths-proposal-for-release-management-methodology/).

The first link tells :

> The rationale here is that it’s costing a lot of time to maintain all those releases for 18 months. It’s also causing a lot of load on the SRU team and on developers to ensure that upgrading from one release to the other won’t cause regressions due to fixes being SRUed only to a few releases.

Comment: I must say, It's very good decision. smart indeed